# String substitution in str.replace vs Pandas str.replace

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace

I need to replace a backslash with something else and wrote this code to test the basic concept. Works fine:

```
test_string = str('19631 location android location you enter an area enable quick action honeywell singl\dzone thermostat environment control and monitoring')
print(test_string)

test_string = test_string.replace('singl\\dzone ','singl_dbl_zone ')
print(test_string)

19631 location android location you enter an area enable quick action honeywell singl\dzone thermostat environment control and monitoring
19631 location android location you enter an area enable quick action honeywell singl_dbl_zone thermostat environment control and monitoring
```

However, I have a pandas df full of these (re-configured) strings and when I try to operate on the df, it doesn't work.

```
raw_corpus.loc[:,'constructed_recipe']=raw_corpus['constructed_recipe'].str.replace('singl\\dzone ','singl_dbl_zone ')
```

The backslash remains!

```
323096  you enter an area android location location environment control and monitoring honeywell singl\dzone thermostat enable quick action
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between `str.replace` and `pd.Series.str.replace`. The former accepts substring replacements, and the latter accepts regex patterns.

Using `str.replace`, you'd need to pass a *raw string* instead.

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'\\d', '_dbl_')
```

Comment: trying the idea, but what is the diff between a "string pattern" and a "pattern?"

Comment: @profhoff Egad, that was a typo... guess I was in two minds, typed out the same thing :D

Comment: Heh. all good! Now to study more about regex patterns and raw strings.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to remove the backslash itself:

```
In [165]: df
Out[165]:
  constructed_recipe
0       singl\dzone

In [166]: df['constructed_recipe'] = df['constructed_recipe'].str.replace(r'\\', '')

In [167]: df
Out[167]:
  constructed_recipe
0        singldzone
```